# Is it possible to play videos from OneDrive in the phone?

Tags: video, onedrive

When I take a picture and upload to OneDrive I can see it on OneDrive app or in the Picture Hub.

With videos I can upload to OneDrive but I can't play them in OneDrive app and it doesn't show in Picture Hub. I know I still can see it in camera roll but after delete I want to see in OneDrive.

Where can I play OneDrive Videos?

Edit: **I want something integrated with OS or official OneDrive app like it does with images.**

Comment: I use an app called SkyMusic to play music files from SkyDrive.  A problem with it is that you cannot seek back or forwards, which is not so much of a problem with music, but it would be a big pain with videos.

Comment: @paradroid Sorry but I want something official. I mean integrated with os or with official SkyDrive app. I will clarify my question. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Edited: Original answer replaced after further clarification of question.

Windows Phone OS itself will only play certain types of video (as Zain states above)

One thing I can add is that you can take your existing videos and re-save them as a .mp4 or .wmv using Windows Live Movie Maker (free). This will save them in a format playable by the phone.Ttherefore letting you stream the video directly from a OneDrive folder using the OneDrive app.

Comment: Good to hear that but I really want to know if someone find a way to do that integrated with OS. ;)

Comment: Yeah, the phone's silverlight is very picky about what video it will play. The codec has to be right. mp4 and wmv will work, but I've come across some mp4 that wouldnt play. The best thing I'd recommend is open the video you want to play from your SkyDrive in Windows Live Movie Maker and save it as a .wmv, I've converted several movies into a playable format from SkyDrive.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Phone only supports certain video formats. I don't know all of them (wmv is one of the supported formats), but you can play videos of those supported types from OneDrive.

For example, if you were to upload a wmv file to OneDrive you'd be able to play it from the [OneDrive app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3).

Comment: I have a video I made with Windows Phone, made upload to SkyDrive and I can't play in the device. There isn't an option to play the file in SkyDrive app.